# How to remove layout groupbox header's bottom border ??

Tags: devexpress-wpf

I using dxlc:LayoutControl and a dxlc:LayoutGroup within it.
I have managed to remove groupbox border by writing following markup .

```
<Style x:Key="layoutGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="dxlc:GroupBox">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

but GroupBox Header's bottom border is still visible.
how can I remove that bottom border of GroupBox Header ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this line, it is necessary to modify templates in our themes

[Please see this link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18580)